# AngularJS - Show nested JSON by object in select optgroups

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I'm trying to create a select with optgroups for countries in the UK, each including a list of their counties that can be selected.

I'm trying to do this using ng-repeat with Angular to access the data, which I can do for single-level arrays in a select, but I'm not sure I've set up my counties array correctly to do this, and the counties are obviously not showing in the list.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehtxcwtk/1/.

HTML:

```
<select data-ng-model="address.county" id="countySelect" material-select watch name="countySelect" class="validate">

    <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>

        <optgroup label="England">

            <option data-ng-repeat="county in counties.england">{{county.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Scotland">

            <option data-ng-repeat="county in counties.scotland">{{county.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Wales">

            <option data-ng-repeat="county in counties.wales">{{county.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Northern Ireland">

            <option data-ng-repeat="county in counties.northernIreland">{{county.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>

    </select>
```

-

Array:

```
var counties = [
    {
        england: [
            {
                name: 'Bath and North East Somerset'
            },
            {
                name: 'Bedfordshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Berkshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Bristol'
            },
            {
                name: 'Buckinghamshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cambridgeshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cheshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cornwall'
            },
            {
                name: 'County Durham'
            },
            {
                name: 'Cumbria'
            },
            {
                name: 'Derbyshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Devon'
            },
            {
                name: 'Dorset'
            },
            {
                name: 'East Riding of Yorkshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'East Sussex'
            },
            {
                name: 'Gloucestershire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Greater London'
            },
            {
                name: 'Greater Manchester'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hampshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Herefordshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Hertfordshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Isle of Wight'
            },
            {
                name: 'Isles of Scilly'
            },
            {
                name: 'Kent'
            },
            {
                name: 'Lancashire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Leicestershire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Lincolnshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Merseyside'
            },
            {
                name: 'Norfolk'
            },
            {
                name: 'North Somerset'
            },
            {
                name: 'North Yorkshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Northamptonshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Northumberland'
            },
            {
                name: 'Nottinghamshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Oxfordshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Rutland'
            },
            {
                name: 'Shropshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Somerset'
            },
            {
                name: 'South Gloucestershire'
            },
            {
                name: 'South Yorkshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Staffordshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Suffolk'
            },
            {
                name: 'Surrey'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tyne and Wear'
            },
            {
                name: 'Warwickshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'West Midlands'
            },
            {
                name: 'West Sussex'
            },
            {
                name: 'West Yorkshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Wiltshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Worcestershire'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        scotland: [
            {
                name: 'Aberdeenshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Angus'
            },
            {
                name: 'Argyll and Bute'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ayrshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Banffshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Berwickshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Borders'
            },
            {
                name: 'Caithness'
            },
            {
                name: 'Clackmannanshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Dumfries and Galloway'
            },
            {
                name: 'Dunbartonshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'East Ayrshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'East Dunbartonshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'East Lothian'
            },
            {
                name: 'East Renfrewshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Fife'
            },
            {
                name: 'Highland'
            },
            {
                name: 'Inverclyde'
            },
            {
                name: 'Kincardineshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Lanarkshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Midlothian'
            },
            {
                name: 'Moray'
            },
            {
                name: 'North Ayrshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'North Lanarkshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Orkney'
            },
            {
                name: 'Perth and Kinross'
            },
            {
                name: 'Renfrewshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Shetland'
            },
            {
                name: 'South Ayrshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'South Lanarkshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'Stirlingshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'West Dunbartonshire'
            },
            {
                name: 'West Lothian'
            },
            {
                name: 'Western Isles'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        wales: [
            {
                name: 'Blaenau Gwent'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Bridgend'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Caerphilly'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Cardiff'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Carmarthenshire'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Ceredigion'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Conwy'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Denbighshire'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Isle of Anglesey'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Merthyr Tydfil'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Monmouthshire'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Neath Port Talbot'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Newport'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Pembrokeshire'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Powys'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Rhundda Cynon Taff'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Swansea'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Torfaen'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Vale of Glamorgan'  
            },
            {
                name: 'Wrexham'  
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        scotland: [
            {
                name: 'Antrim'
            },
            {
                name: 'Armagh'
            },
            {
                name: 'Down'
            },
            {
                name: 'Fermanagh'
            },
            {
                name: 'Londonderry'
            },
            {
                name: 'Tyrone'
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `county object` is in a wrong format. It needs to be an `object` and it should contain all the counties as `objects`. Just look at the following example. I corrected your object to work properly.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {

  //Correct county object format
  //////////////////////////////
  $scope.counties = {
    england: [{
        name: 'Bath and North East Somerset'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bedfordshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Berkshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bristol'
      },
      {
        name: 'Buckinghamshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cambridgeshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cheshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cornwall'
      },
      {
        name: 'County Durham'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cumbria'
      },
      {
        name: 'Derbyshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Devon'
      },
      {
        name: 'Dorset'
      },
      {
        name: 'East Riding of Yorkshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'East Sussex'
      },
      {
        name: 'Gloucestershire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Greater London'
      },
      {
        name: 'Greater Manchester'
      },
      {
        name: 'Hampshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Herefordshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Hertfordshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Isle of Wight'
      },
      {
        name: 'Isles of Scilly'
      },
      {
        name: 'Kent'
      },
      {
        name: 'Lancashire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Leicestershire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Lincolnshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Merseyside'
      },
      {
        name: 'Norfolk'
      },
      {
        name: 'North Somerset'
      },
      {
        name: 'North Yorkshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Northamptonshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Northumberland'
      },
      {
        name: 'Nottinghamshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Oxfordshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Rutland'
      },
      {
        name: 'Shropshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Somerset'
      },
      {
        name: 'South Gloucestershire'
      },
      {
        name: 'South Yorkshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Staffordshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Suffolk'
      },
      {
        name: 'Surrey'
      },
      {
        name: 'Tyne and Wear'
      },
      {
        name: 'Warwickshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'West Midlands'
      },
      {
        name: 'West Sussex'
      },
      {
        name: 'West Yorkshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wiltshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Worcestershire'
      }
    ],
    scotland: [{
        name: 'Aberdeenshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Angus'
      },
      {
        name: 'Argyll and Bute'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ayrshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Banffshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Berwickshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Borders'
      },
      {
        name: 'Caithness'
      },
      {
        name: 'Clackmannanshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Dumfries and Galloway'
      },
      {
        name: 'Dunbartonshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'East Ayrshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'East Dunbartonshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'East Lothian'
      },
      {
        name: 'East Renfrewshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Fife'
      },
      {
        name: 'Highland'
      },
      {
        name: 'Inverclyde'
      },
      {
        name: 'Kincardineshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Lanarkshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Midlothian'
      },
      {
        name: 'Moray'
      },
      {
        name: 'North Ayrshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'North Lanarkshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Orkney'
      },
      {
        name: 'Perth and Kinross'
      },
      {
        name: 'Renfrewshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Shetland'
      },
      {
        name: 'South Ayrshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'South Lanarkshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Stirlingshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'West Dunbartonshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'West Lothian'
      },
      {
        name: 'Western Isles'
      }
    ],
    wales: [{
        name: 'Blaenau Gwent'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bridgend'
      },
      {
        name: 'Caerphilly'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cardiff'
      },
      {
        name: 'Carmarthenshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ceredigion'
      },
      {
        name: 'Conwy'
      },
      {
        name: 'Denbighshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Isle of Anglesey'
      },
      {
        name: 'Merthyr Tydfil'
      },
      {
        name: 'Monmouthshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Neath Port Talbot'
      },
      {
        name: 'Newport'
      },
      {
        name: 'Pembrokeshire'
      },
      {
        name: 'Powys'
      },
      {
        name: 'Rhundda Cynon Taff'
      },
      {
        name: 'Swansea'
      },
      {
        name: 'Torfaen'
      },
      {
        name: 'Vale of Glamorgan'
      },
      {
        name: 'Wrexham'
      }
    ],
    scotland: [{
        name: 'Antrim'
      },
      {
        name: 'Armagh'
      },
      {
        name: 'Down'
      },
      {
        name: 'Fermanagh'
      },
      {
        name: 'Londonderry'
      },
      {
        name: 'Tyrone'
      },
    ]
  };

  //Default county
  $scope.address = {
    county: "Bristol"
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">

  <select ng-model="address.county" id="countySelect" material-select watch name="countySelect" class="validate">

    <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>

        <optgroup label="England">

            <option data-ng-repeat="county in counties.england">{{county.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Scotland">

            <option data-ng-repeat="county in counties.scotland">{{county.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Wales">

            <option data-ng-repeat="county in counties.wales">{{county.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Northern Ireland">

            <option data-ng-repeat="county in counties.northernIreland">{{county.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>

    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, knew I'd messed up the object somehow

Answer (score 0):

Your data is structured as an array. Try turning `counties` into an Object instead, since you're trying to access properties in your template code. Like so:

```
var counties =
    {
        england: [
            {
                name: 'Bath and North East Somerset'
            },
            ...
    }
```

instead of

```
var counties = [
    {
        england: [
            {
                name: 'Bath and North East Somerset'
            },
            ...
    }
]
```

If you can't change the data model, try accessing them in your template like so as a workaround:

`data-ng-repeat="county in counties[0].scotland"`

Answer (score 0):

you made a tiny mistake when addressing/setting up your counties list. You are referring to counties.england but in your data structure it is rather counties[0].england. Please see this working codepen: https://codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/XegMJQ

The important part is the removed array from the beginning:

```
$scope.counties = {
        england: [
            {
                name: 'Bath and North East Somerset'
            },
...
```

In case it needs further clarification please let me know and will add some further detail!